# Details of Bing Confidence Levels

Tags: geocoding, bing-api, bing-maps

Has anyone found a more complete description of what the [Bing Confidence Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966762.aspx) values actually mean?

I'm trying to reconcile the results against another source of address data that has confidence values such as City, Street and Specific Address, and I want to get a feel for where the Bing results sit on this scale. I'm using the RESTful API.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966762.aspx) only states that "High = The geocode service has high confidence in the match." etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the MSDN documentation, you will be able to find various values for this property.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701725.aspx

Extracted from the documentation:

> The level of confidence that the geocoded location result is a match.
>   Use this value with the match code to determine for more complete
>   information about the match.
>
> The confidence of a geocoded location is based on many factors
>   including the relative importance of the geocoded location and the
>   user’s location, if specified. The following description provides more
>   information about how confidence scores are assigned and how results
>   are ranked.
>
> If the confidence is set to High, one or more strong matches were
>   found. Multiple High confidence matches are sorted in ranked order by
>   importance when applicable. For example, landmarks have importance but
>   addresses do not.
>
> If a request includes a user location or a map area (see User Context
>   Parameters), then the ranking may change appropriately. For example, a
>   location query for "Paris" returns "Paris, France" and "Paris, TX"
>   both with High confidence. "Paris, France" is always ranked first due
>   to importance unless a user location indicates that the user is in or
>   very close to Paris, TX or the map view indicates that the user is
>   searching in that area.
>
> In some situations, the returned match may not be at the same level as
>   the information provided in the request. For example, a request may
>   specify address information and the geocode service may only be able
>   to match a postal code. In this case, if the geocode service has a
>   high confidence that the postal code matches the data, the confidence
>   is set to High and the match code is set to UpHierarchy to specify
>   that it could not match all of the information and had to search
>   up-hierarchy.
>
> If the location information in the query is ambiguous, and there is no
>   additional information to rank the locations (such as user location or
>   the relative importance of the location), the confidence is set to
>   Medium. For example, a location query for "148th Ave, Bellevue" may
>   return "148th Ave SE" and "148th Ave NE" both with Medium confidence.
>
> If the location information in the query does not provide enough
>   information to geocode a specific location, a less precise location
>   value may be returned and the confidence is set to Medium. For
>   example, if an address is provided, but a match is not found for the
>   house number, the geocode result with a Roadblock entity type may be
>   returned. You can check the entityType field value to determine what
>   type of entity the geocode result represents. For a list of entity
>   types, see Entity Types.